# Select2 - Display only a limited number of items and show the rest as 'n' more

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've started working with Select2 and I've found it really useful for my needs. But, there seems to be a small design issue that's disturbing other elements on the page. When I select more items than those can fit in the specified width, the select box expands by itself.

HTML:

```
<select id="selector" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="7">Option 7</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selector").select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
        width: 'resolve',
        dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
        allowClear: 'true'
    });
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle of the Select2 demo I've made: https://jsfiddle.net/opztx0g5/

Here are the screenshots:

1. before expansion

[image: before expansion]

2. after expansion

[image: after expansion]

I've found this but didn't find a way to implement it,

[image: n more options]

I would like to know if there's a option to do just that, so that it doesn't disturb the page design.

Thanks!

Comment: Head to https://github.com/select2/select2 and read the docs, if you didn't found the option, so go head and open an issue for adding such an option

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you show Dropdown with simply setting the height for Dropdown.

It can be done by making CSS changes as below

```
 .select2-container .select2-selection--single { height: 33px !important; }
```

or

```
.select2-selection { height: auto !important;}
```

Something you looking for can be found here  - [Tagging with multi-value select boxes](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes)

Hope it will help you!!!!!

Comment: The CSS changes you suggested aren't helping, the box expands even after that. The link you referred to isn't helpful as well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: can you please cross check between the DOM being formed and CSS I have given. In order to solve the issue, we need to create the selector on the basis of DOM being generated. I too got a reference from someone. Accordingly, I have done changes in my CSS

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest an alternative to Select2, Jquery.sumoselect.

It has a feature (csvDispCount) that would let you display the number of items selected after a specified count.

Refer http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I prefer using Select2. The UI of Select2 is far better than that of Jquery.sumoselect